# java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: no further information

Tags: java, linux, windows, sockets, tcp

I'm using TCP from Akka IO to make a TCP connection. I have a TCP socket listening on 127.0.0.1 port 2001 and I'm trying to connect to that socket, but from the network interface with address 192.168.101.20, which is the (local) address of my Ethernet adapter. When I do this on a Linux OS everything works fine; I can create a connection and I'm able send and receive messages. When I, however, do this on a Windows (7) OS I cannot seem to get a connection. All I get is the following exception:

> java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: no further information

Since I first encountered this with the Akka IO module I extracted the Java code responsible for making the connection and adjusted it to be run in a simple main class:

```java
final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2001);
final InetSocketAddress localAddress = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.101.20", 0);
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        final Socket socket = new ServerSocket(remoteAddress.getPort(), 100,
                remoteAddress.getAddress()).accept();
        System.out.println("Connection astablished with ["
                + socket.getInetAddress() + "]");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}).start();
System.out.println("Attempting connection to [" + remoteAddress + "]");

/* Code making a connection */
final SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) SocketChannel.open()
        .configureBlocking(false);
channel.socket().bind(localAddress);
if (!channel.connect(remoteAddress)) {
    int retries = 3;
    while (!channel.finishConnect() && --retries > 0) {  // Throws BindException
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    if (retries == 0) {
        throw new IOException("Could not establish connection");
    }
}
```

*Note: The local address might need to be changed depending on the address of the Ethernet adapter.*

This can also be shown by using a simple `Socket` implementation:

```java
/* Code making a connection */
final Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(localAddress);
socket.connect(remoteAddress); // Throws ConnectException
```

> java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine

Anybody an idea why this works on Linux, but not on Windows?

Comment: Get rid of the bind. You don't need it for an outbound socket. And spin-looping in a non-blocking connect is pointless. You should either use a Selector or keep the channel in blocking mode.

Comment: NB This cannot possibly be the real code. It prints a failure message even if the connect succeeds.

Comment: I know you don't need a bind, but that's not the point. It's a unit test where I need to make multiple connections to the same server (all on the same machine), so I'm using the local bind address to select the different network interfaces. This works fine under Linux, so why doesn't it work under Windows?

Comment: If the connect succeeds it prints "Connected", but only if there is a server listening on port 2001 (of 127.0.0.1), otherwise you'll get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` indicating that the initial connect is succeeded.

Comment: Not a valid test. If you're connecting to 127.0.0.1 it doesn't make any sense to bind to anything except 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0, and you can't do the latter for sockets you intend to connect. You should let the system determine the binding when it sees the connect target. You aren't testing anything useful here.

Comment: I'm not testing the sockets or connections. I'm testing the expected behavior of the server with multiple connections. Ofcourse in 'normal' circumstances the server is not bound to 127.0.0.1 but an specific address and are the connections coming from outside (the machine).

Comment: But you're not testing the normal case. You're testing a special case, with the listener bound to 127.0.0.1 and the client bound to 192.168.10.20., and which appears to be not a local IP address of the client host.